# ExpressJS web app using mlab; database sorting issues

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, mongoose, mlab

I built a nodeJS web app with mongoose hosted on heroku with mlab database and it's a book blog. Everything works, but I just entered an 11th book, and in the index view it used to sort by date added, with most recent on top, but this 11th book just nested itself at index 3. Can someone explain me first who would dictate that (nodejs, mongoose, heroku, mlab) and then how to make sure that it won't happen in the future?
The model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');


var bookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    author: String,
    image: String,
    yearPublish: String,
    review: String,
    created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    score: {type:Number, max:10, min:0}
});

var Book = mongoose.model('Book', bookSchema);
module.exports = Book;
```

The routes:

```
var express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router(),
    Book = require('../models/book'),
    User = require('../models/user');


    /// RESTFUL ROUTES ///

// INDEX route
router.get('/books', function(req,res){
    //passing reviewers in index.ejs

    Book.find({}, function(err, books){
        if(err){
            console.log('error loading from DB...')
        }
        else{
            res.render('books/index', {books:books});
        }
    });

});
// NEW route
router.get('/books/new',isloggedIn, function(req,res){
    res.render('books/new');
});
//CREATE route
router.post('/books', isloggedIn, function(req,res){
    Book.create(req.body.book, function(err, newBook){
        if(err){
            console.log('error creating new book review');
            console.log(err);
        }
        else{
            res.redirect('/books');
        }
    });
});
//SHOW route
router.get('/books/:id', function(req,res){

    Book.findById(req.params.id, function(err, theBook){
        if(err){
            res.redirect('/books')
        }
        else{
            res.render('books/show', {book:theBook});
        }
    });

});
//EDIT route
router.get('/books/:id/edit',isloggedIn, function(req,res){
    Book.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundBook){
        if(err){
            res.redirect('/');
        }
        else{
            res.render('books/edit', {book: foundBook});
        }
    });
});
//UPDATE route
router.put('/books/:id',isloggedIn, function(req,res){
    Book.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body.book ,function(err, foundBook){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else{
            res.redirect('/books/' + req.params.id);
        }
    });
});
// DELETE route
router.delete('/books/:id',isloggedIn, function(req,res){

        Book.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function(err, foundBook){
            if(err){
                console.log('could not delete from DB...')
                res.redirect('/')
            }
            else{
                res.redirect('/');
            }
        });
});

function isloggedIn(req,res,next){
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        if(req.user.username == 'jc.taillandier'){
            return next();
        }
        else{
            res.redirect('/books')
        }
    }
    else{
        res.redirect('/books')
    }
}

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: What do You mean by nested - UI, mongo model? How does it look like in db?

Comment: I just meant nested between two other entries instead of at the end. In mlab, it's at index 3 of the collection, but it should be at the end ie. index 11

Comment: When you fetch all the books, the 11th book also is index 3 position? Or it just happened in mlab? Could you share book model code?

Comment: Can You provide the code where You insert and display data?

Comment: @VitoMadio the 11th book I entered was saved in mlab at index 3, and is rendered at index 3. AND I just tried adding another, and it goes to that place again, right above the 11th entered, so in index 4.

Comment: MongoDB doesn't guarantee that documents are kept in the order of insertion. If you want to receive documents in a particular order, you will have to sort the documents. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-sort

Comment: Sorting on the `created` field should give you what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case don't mind about how mlab sort items you just need to sort them by created date at moment of fetching:

```
Book.find().sort({created: -1}).exec(function(err, books){ etc...
```

Hope it helps.
P.S. Use -1 for descending order and 1 for ascending

Comment: Thanks, only thing now is
Error: sort() only takes 1 Argument